# Row to column for frequency in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
> initial
  Name Status
1    a    Win
2    b    Win
3    c   Loss
```

From here I want a data frame which looks like this

```
> final
  Name Win Loss
1    a   1    0
2    b   1    0
3    c   0    1
```

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the base function table?

```
initial=data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"),
                   status=c("win","loss","win"))
  name status
1    a    win
2    b   loss
3    c    win


table(initial)

  name loss win
   a    0   1
   b    1   0
   c    0   1
```

The function `table` returns a table object. To convert it to a `data.frame` of the sort you like, using the command  `as.data.frame` will not help, since that dispatches the function `as.data.frame.table`. Instead you should pass the table to `as.data.frame.matrix`

```
final_data_frame= as.data.frame.matrix(table(initial))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(initial, Name~Status, value.var='Status', length)
#  Name Loss Win
#1    a    0   1
#2    b    0   1
#3    c    1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `model.matrix()` to create the columns:

```
model.matrix(Name ~ -1 + Status, data = initial)

  StatusLoss StatusWin
1          0         1
2          0         1
3          1         0
```